# faster complete() within grouped df, using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Yesterday [I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76073019/full-join-on-grouped-df-but-keep-grouped-values-from-left-side) about how to expand/complete within group values.

Testing the solution on a minimal example df worked great, but on my real data, it's not computing after several hours.

My dplyr pipe flow looks like this:

```
mydf <- mydf |>
group_by_at(vars(id:trial_day)) |> 
  summarise_at(vars(bla:last_col()), sum) |> 
  complete(trial_day = 1:14)
```

I tried swapping out `complete()` for `expand()` but doing so results in the grouped vars only being kept, the other vars are dropped e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep('a', 5),
  x = 6:10,
  y = 5:1
)

# returns all cols
df |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  complete(x = 1:10)

# only returns id and x, no y
df |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  expand(x = 1:10)
```

But I'm not sure if expand would even be any faster.

I tried doing a right join onto a df `ladder = data.frame(day = 1:14)` but that resulted in the expanded rows having NA for the grouping vars, I wanted those to fill whenever an expansion took place.

Is there a faster way to get the same result as I do using `complete()`?

Comment: Related non-tidyverse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712379/efficient-way-to-fill-time-series-per-group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having a fixed value to expand across groups like in the example you have shared, you don't need to add `group_by`. We want to `complete` fixed values (`1:10`) irrespective of the group it is in.

If you remove `group_by` from your code the code is faster 3 times when compared it with grouped data. I have created a larger example to demonstrate this.

```
# New example data
df <- data.frame(
  id = sample(c(letters, LETTERS), 1e6, replace = TRUE),
  x = sample(9, 1e6, replace = TRUE),
  y = sample(5, 1e6, replace = TRUE)
)

# compare the results with and without group_by and make sure they are the same

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

res1 <- df |> group_by(id) |> complete(x = 1:10) |> ungroup() |> arrange(id)
res2 <- df |> complete(id, x = 1:10) |> arrange(id)

identical(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE

# Check the performance
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  with_group = df |> group_by(id) |> complete(x = 1:10), 
  without_group = df |> complete(id, x = 1:10)
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#          expr       min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#    with_group 257.97722 290.68443 354.1348 311.0921 344.7817 673.3979   100  a 
# without_group  76.98431  98.45134 144.6897 107.9547 116.0458 539.7276   100   b
```

Comment: `complete(id, x = 1:10)` you mean put the grouping var id within complete() itself. OK, but if I actually have multiple grouping vars? Tried e.g. `complete(id:bla, x = 1:10)` but that didn't work

Comment: "That didn't work" isn't very helpful.  Your expected output is not clear to me.  Have you looked at `nesting()`?  Also, `group_by_at`, `summarise_at`  and the like have been superseded.

Comment: Looking at docs, there's no explicit way I can see to pass multiple grouping vars https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html

Comment: @DougFir I couldn't find a way to use `:` or other tidyselect helper functions in `complete`. So what you need to do is `complete(id, col1, col2, bla, x = 1:10)`

Comment: @DougFir I found this method from here https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/1397#issuecomment-1260747538 `df |> complete(!!!rlang::syms(df %>% select(id:bla) %>% names), x = 1:10)`

Answer (score -1):

We could use `bind_rows()` with swapping `x` and `y`:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df, df %>% 
            select(id, x=y, y=x))
```

output:

```
  id  x  y
1   a  6  5
2   a  7  4
3   a  8  3
4   a  9  2
5   a 10  1
6   a  5  6
7   a  4  7
8   a  3  8
9   a  2  9
10  a  1 10
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = rep('a', 5),
  x = 6:10,
  y = 5:1
)
```